# Deep link open wrong app if there are some apps that have defined almost similar path in intent filter Android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have 2 app that have intent-filter as following:

App 1:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:path="/auth/validation/au"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and App 2:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="example.com"
                android:path="/auth/validation/va"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then I install App 1 and App 2 and try to open App 1 with this link https://example.com/auth/validation/au?token=XYZ but App 2 is always launched instead. Any wrong config I made?

Comment: your domain is same android:host="example.com", try with different domain it will work

Comment: @sasikumar I am aware about the host domain. In my case, I had to use the same domain and I cannot follow what you suggested. That is why it causes me this problem. Do you have another suggestion for my case?